# I cannot update my Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I am getting repeated notices that my Windows 10 update is unsuccessful:

[image]

WHen I attempt to Download and Install manually, it finds an update, attempts to install, and then reports:

> Updates failed
>
> There were problems installing some updates, but we'll try again later.

It doesn’t work later either.

I have run the Troubleshooting several times, and get the following:

> **Troubleshooting has completed**
>
> The troubleshooter made some changes to your system. Try attempting the task you were trying to do before.
>
> **Problems found**
>
> Check for Windows Update issues Detected

Needless to say, that doesn’t fix the problem.

I have tried all of the above many times, which could be one of the symptoms of insanity.

Any suggestions on what to try next, sort of a total reinstall?

My current system is:

Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 1909
Installed on 26/09/2020
OS build 18363.1082

UPDATE

This is looking silly. Both SFC and DISM have failed. Running setup.exe from the mounted ISO failed. Starting from the mounted ISO and installing from there failed.

I may have to install from scratch.

Comment: 1909 hasn’t been supported for nearly 2 years. Have you tried downloading a supported feature update by using a Windows ISO and mounting and launching setup.exe? Make sure the App Readiness and windows installer service is running. Even the 1909 cumulative update you have installed is out of date, which means, Windows Update hasn’t been working for awhile now. [Edit] your question with any additional inputs from those attempts

Comment: Would the age be the problem? I have tried using sfc and dism to repair what appear to be corrupt files, and I am now waiting for a new ISO to be downloaded.

Comment: You might download the latest Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft and perform an install, keeping files. Before doing this, though, *make an image of the disk*, lest something go wrong.

Comment: @Manngo - No; Corrupt system files are likely the true reason you haven't been able to install updates for over a year.  Were the services I wanted information on running?

Answer (score 4):

You need to upgrade to a supported version of Windows 10, to begin with. There are various ways to do this, but I'd suggest creating a bootable USB of the latest Windows 10 version and doing an upgrade install. This should be a more complete repair and, because it won't rely on the current, faulty, files, there's a better chance it will go through successfully and resolve the underlying issues causing your current update issues.

Comment: I’m getting this message: “The upgrade option isn't available if you start your computer using Windows installation media.”

Comment: First, it's worth trying logging into Windows, running the installer from the USB, and trying the in place upgrade. If that doesn't work, you'll need to boot to the USB and try a Refresh install, and if that isn't an option, your final choice is to run a Reset install from the USB. The Reset is the last choice because, while it does keep your files, programs you've installed will be lost during the reset.